# jQuery set scope of method

Tags: jquery, scope, callback

I just wondered if something like this can be achieved:

Assume that I have a event callback inside my library defined:

```js
var app = {
        globals: {
            foo: null
        },
        bar: function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
            if (typeof app.globals.foo === "function") app.globals.foo(e);
        },
        init: function(options) {
            $.extend(app.globals, options);
            $(".myclass").on("click", function(e) {
                app.bar(e);
            });
        }
    };

    $(document).ready(function() {
        app.init({
            foo: function(evt) {
                alert("clicked");
                console.log(evt.target);
            }
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="myclass">Click Me!</div>
```

With this method, I'm passing the ".myclass" elements' click event data to `app.foo`, so the object oriented method would be executed.

**TL;DR:** The question is, can I set the scope of foo as the object which sent the click event? So:

```
app.init({
   foo: function(){
       console.log(this);
   }
});
```

would be executed same as:

```
app.init({
   foo: function(evt){
       console.log(evt.target);
   }
});
```

Is something like this possible?

Comment: does any of this works for you? (Specifically, `app.foo`?)

Comment: Yes it basically works. The code that I wrote is not tested, just written out of my head to give you an idea what I mean.

Comment: Then please make sure you post valid code and not scribbles. This code is broken and it's pointless to discuss it.

Comment: Now it's running. You can test it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *can* control the `this` value for the `foo` function on activation:

```
// ...
if(typeof app.globals.foo === "function") app.globals.foo.call(e.target);
// ...
```

Will set the `this` to be equal to `e.target` and you'll get the behavior you described, however...

It's not a good practice to do so. First, if `foo` is bound to a specific `this` (for example via `foo.bind(someContext)` this method will fail to override that context. Second, it's unnatural to have a `this` context when there's no real object context - that's what function arguments are used for. The "common exception" to this (often found in jQuery callbacks) is passing the context to an "isolated" callback function, not an "object method", and even then it's hard to justify this because of the same reason, function arguments are much clearer and less fragile.

Comment: So the `.call(e.target)` is defining the scope there right? I basically wanted a bridge between a click callback and a click object method, so I can carry the whole click event callback to that object method safely. For example, someone has a method full of `$(this)` (I know, should've buffered - bad practice), and he/she wants to copy that method directly to a library. That would be useful.

Comment: @TahaPaksu - that would *usually* work, I just think it's ill advised.